# Why is my input textbox hiding part of the characters

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The top and bottom of the text is being cut off. This only happens in IE - what do you suppose is causing this? How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: It's a little hard to tell whats going on with only an image..

Comment: Perhaps you could include some code?

Answer (score 1):

```
line-height
```

What is it set to? Try increasing it for IE